# jstree support for Right to left languages not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tree, jstree

I'm developing an web app in Arabic and i need to use a tree view to reprent my data. I looked around and found that jstree is the best in this area.
The tree works fine when using the default theme (which is LTR), but when i switched to a built-in theme called default-rtl, i didnt see any changes. I looked around in firebug and the script is indeed loading the appropriate css file. Here is my code:

```
$("#tree").bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) {
    // My handler function here
}).bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    // another function here        
}).jstree({
    core: {
        "animation": 0
    },
    "themes" : {
        "rtl": true,
        "theme" : "default-rtl",
        "url": "js/libs/jstree/themes/default-rtl/style.css",
        "dots" : false,
        "icons" : true
    },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "ui"]
});
```

is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Still no answers? Someone help please.

Comment: I managed to fixed this using my own css, if someone has the same issue, please contact me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue.

I modifed this CSS file (attached) a little bit and included it in the
CSS folder that comes with JSTREE (usually it's called default.css or
default-rtl). You can download it from here: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?ah26sq0b0isbboa

Make sure you don't have any

```
ul {
     overflow: hidden
}
```

related to
your ul root element of ur tree

Hope that was clear,

Enjoy,

Answer (score 0):

Please Set Core RTL Option To True

Comment: in which file and where can it be found ? thanks